# Pass validationData to Cognito post authentication trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

In Cognito, is there a way to pass validationData from pre-authentication trigger to post-authentication trigger? I want to pass a data that can be used to create an Endpoint (SNS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both triggers are unique. Unfortunately there is no way to pass validation data from pre authentication trigger response to post authentication trigger request. The response from pre authentication trigger is ignored as per the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-auth